# From Percentage in Non Decimal Numbers

Tags: delphi, timer, numbers

I have this code to record a video in my program:

```
pbVideoProgress.Percent := Round((vidrec / MAX_REC) * 100);
```

Now my problem is I want to put a label on my program that will display a timer before the next video will be shown, I tried this:

```
Label1.Caption :=inttostr(pbVideoProgress.Percent) ;
```

But it will display the percentage from 100% until it reaches 0% (so next video will be shown).
How can I chang that percentage from % in a real number such as from 10, 9... until 0?

Comment: are u trying to display the caption 10 sec prior to video end and start the countdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code line you showed is not valid Delphi syntax.  You have to use separate statements:

```
pbVideoProgress.Percent := Round((vidrec / MAX_REC) * 100);
...
Label1.Caption := IntToStr(100 - pbVideoProgress.Percent);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try. You really give me an idea.